# is firebase limited to display only 4kb file JSON response?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using ship engine to place an order through shipment mode of delivery.I am using cloud functions to call shipment API
Total response file size provided by ship engine  is 23kb, but firebase is limited to 4kb. what to do in such cases?. How to limit the data to get or extract specific fields from the response?

JSON response

```
{
  "rate_response": {
    "rates": [
      {
        "rate_id": "se-21014522",
        "rate_type": "shipment",
        "carrier_id": "se-341525",
        "shipping_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.47
        },
        "insurance_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "confirmation_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "other_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "zone": 4,
        "package_type": "letter",
        "delivery_days": 4,
        "guaranteed_service": false,
        "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-09-07T00:00:00Z",
        "carrier_delivery_days": "3",
        "ship_date": "2018-09-03T00:00:00Z",
        "negotiated_rate": false,
        "service_type": "USPS First Class Mail",
        "service_code": "usps_first_class_mail",
        "trackable": true,
        "carrier_code": "stamps_com",
        "carrier_nickname": "Free",
        "carrier_friendly_name": "Stamps.com",
        "validation_status": "valid",
        "warning_messages": [],
        "error_messages": []
      },
      {
        "rate_id": "se-21014523",
        "rate_type": "shipment",
        "carrier_id": "se-341525",
        "shipping_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 1.00
        },
        "insurance_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "confirmation_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "other_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "zone": 4,
        "package_type": "large_envelope_or_flat",
        "delivery_days": 4,
        "guaranteed_service": false,
        "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-09-07T00:00:00Z",
        "carrier_delivery_days": "3",
        "ship_date": "2018-09-03T00:00:00Z",
        "negotiated_rate": false,
        "service_type": "USPS First Class Mail",
        "service_code": "usps_first_class_mail",
        "trackable": true,
        "carrier_code": "stamps_com",
        "carrier_nickname": "Free",
        "carrier_friendly_name": "Stamps.com",
        "validation_status": "valid",
        "warning_messages": [],
        "error_messages": []
      },
      {
        "rate_id": "se-21014524",
        "rate_type": "shipment",
        "carrier_id": "se-341525",
        "shipping_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 2.66
        },
        "insurance_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "confirmation_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "other_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "zone": 4,
        "package_type": "package",
        "delivery_days": 4,
        "guaranteed_service": false,
        "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-09-07T00:00:00Z",
        "carrier_delivery_days": "3",
        "ship_date": "2018-09-03T00:00:00Z",
        "negotiated_rate": false,
        "service_type": "USPS First Class Mail",
        "service_code": "usps_first_class_mail",
        "trackable": true,
        "carrier_code": "stamps_com",
        "carrier_nickname": "Free",
        "carrier_friendly_name": "Stamps.com",
        "validation_status": "valid",
        "warning_messages": [],
        "error_messages": []
      },
      {
        "rate_id": "se-21014525",
        "rate_type": "shipment",
        "carrier_id": "se-341525",
        "shipping_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 6.89
        },
        "insurance_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "confirmation_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "other_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 0.00
        },
        "zone": 4,
        "package_type": "package",
        "delivery_days": 3,
        "guaranteed_service": false,
        "estimated_delivery_date": "2018-09-06T00:00:00Z",
        "carrier_delivery_days": "2",
        "ship_date": "2018-09-03T00:00:00Z",
        "negotiated_rate": false,
        "service_type": "USPS Priority Mail",
        "service_code": "usps_priority_mail",
        "trackable": true,
        "carrier_code": "stamps_com",
        "carrier_nickname": "Free",
        "carrier_friendly_name": "Stamps.com",
        "validation_status": "valid",
        "warning_messages": [],
        "error_messages": []
      },
      {
        "rate_id": "se-21014526",
        "rate_type": "shipment",
        "carrier_id": "se-341525",
        "shipping_amount": {
          "currency": "usd",
          "amount": 12.45
        },
        "insurance_amount": {
```

Above half JSON is only displaying in firebase console
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to limit your messaging payload to 4K, then have your client app fetch the remaining data, if necessary.